# Программа падает еще не запустившись: During startup program exited with code 0xc0000018

Tags: c++, clion

`Clion 2017.1`
Пытаюсь запустить Hello world. Программа успешно собирается, но при запуске падает с

```
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000018.
```

Если запускать в режиме отладки с брейком на `main`, то выясняется, что `main` не вызывается - программа падает где-то еще раньше.

Компилировал MinGW с версиями gcc `4.7.1`, `5.1.0` и `6.3.0` - на всех одно и то же. Все на винде.

Собственно, что делать?

---

К слову, в Code::Block с тем же компилятором gcc 4.7.1 все успешно собралось и работает - проблема где-то в clion-e

---

Добавил код программы

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Все же хотелось бы посмотреть на исходник - там точно только Hello world и все?...

Comment: @Harry, добавил код программы. Там точно только Hello world. Он нормально собирается и запускается в CodeBlock, но падает при запуске, если собрать в CLion. Компилятор один и тот же. При запуске в режиме отладке не срабатывает даже брейкпоинт, стоящий на мейне